# Any other ways to evaluate $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n k {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, problem-solving

> $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n k {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ with $0<p<1$

I know of one way to evaluate it (from statistics) but I was wondering if there are any other ways.

This is the way I know:

Let

$$M(t)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n e^{kt} {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Then $$M(t)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (pe^t)^k (1-p)^{n-k}=(pe^t+1-p)^n$$

$$M'(t)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n ke^{kt} {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}=pe^tn(pe^t+1-p)^{n-1}$$

$$M'(0)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n k {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}=np$$

Comment: I feel like this is way too similar to what you did to deserve its own answer, but you can use $x^{k}$ in place of $e^{kt}$, differentiate w.r.t $x$, and then set $x=1$. It seems simpler to me that way.

Comment: @SpiralRain Thanks for that remark I didn't think of using different functions; I had tunnel vision because I was only thinking of the momeng generating function.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
&= \sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
= \sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-1-(k-1))!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
&=np\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-1-(k-1))!} p^{k-1} (1-p)^{n-1-(k-1)}\\
&=np\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{\ell!(n-1-\ell)!} p^{\ell} (1-p)^{n-1-\ell}\\
&=np\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{\ell} p^{\ell} (1-p)^{n-1-\ell}\\
&= np.
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Ovi Thanks. ${}{}$

Comment: Ah nice trick of overriding the character limit, I learned two things from you $:)$ ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different variation of an answer already given which might also be convenient.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}
> &=np(1-p)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{k-1}\tag{1}\\
> &=np(1-p)^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{k}\tag{2}\\
> &=np(1-p)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{n-1}\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=np}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and we factor out $p(1-p)^{n-1}$ to prepare the index shift of the next line.
- In (2) we shift the index to start from $k=0$.
- In (3) we use the binomial summation formula.
- In (4) we do some final simplifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can also notice that this is the expectation $E(X)$ where $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$, and $E(X)=n\,p$.

Comment: Yes this is where the problem originally came from, I was trying to derive the expectation myself. When I failed I looked in a book and they had the proof I wrote in the OP.