# Expected number of heads in n coin tosses

Tags: probability, expectation

What is the expected number of heads in n coin tosses, where the probability of landing one head is p?

I know that the probability of having k heads in n tosses is
$$\ \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

So, the expected number of heads in n tosses is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

But I'm not sure how to simplify this further. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This should be very simple right? The expected number of heads for one toss is $p$. Therefore the expected number of heads for $n$ tosses is $np$ by linearity of expectation.

Comment: Oh yes of course! Thanks

Comment: Tim, it is still possible to simplify the above expression, despite  the fact that it is easier by the above method to see that the answer is $np$.

Comment: Linearity of expectation is the simple, natural, elegant way to get $np$. Another way is [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485261/any-other-ways-to-evaluate-displaystyle-sum-k-0n-k-n-choose-k-pk-1-p/2485271).